# Using HoloEveryWhere and RoboGuiuce Activity

Tags: android, roboguice, android-holo-everywhere

I import `HoloEveryWhere` and  `HoloEverywhere Addon Roboguice` then i added `HoloEveryWhere` to the `HoloEverywhere Addon Roboguice` and every thing is fine no error.In my project i added `HoloEverywhere Addon Roboguice`  . Now if i want to make an `Activity` what Activity should I extend ? i tried

```
public class HomeActivity extends IAddonActivity{

...
..
..
}
```

I got `ClassCastException`

full stackTrace

```
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testingroboguicewithholoeverywhere/com.example.testingroboguicewithholoeverywhere.BaseActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testingroboguicewithholoeverywhere.BaseActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testingroboguicewithholoeverywhere.BaseActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
09-16 14:54:11.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16138):    ... 11 more
```

which `class` should i extend to have an `Activity`

to be able to use `HoloEveryWhere` and `RoboGuice` together .